# Tokens with close button

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uistackview

I'm trying to think of the best approach to get an interface like this:

[image: tokens with x button]

They are similar to the Stack Overflow tokens that you enter when asking a question, except I don't need to be able to type the tokens in, just add/remove them programmatically.

[image]

As you can see, they are left aligned, variable width, and something can be triggered by the 'x' button.

UICollectionView seems overkill. UIStackView will only allow one row (?). UITextField / UITextView doesn't work well with images. What is the right approach to take?

Answer (score 3):

**UICollectionView** is what you're looking for, it doesn't seem overkill. Unless you want to implement a custom solution.

Answer (score 2):

I need same functionality, I little investigate possible solutions, and this one look as good startpoint [CloudTagView](https://github.com/Morbix/CloudTagView)

Answer (score 2):

This is perfect for you, written in **Swift**:

https://github.com/xhacker/TagListView

This can be also used, written in **Objective-C**:

https://github.com/ali312/TLTagsControl

In case you choose obj-c library, here is [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)